# C# Entity Framework 6 MySQL - Unknown column being referenced on insert ApplicationUser_Id

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6 with MySQL. Here are 2 of my models:

```
public class AppSession
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(36)]
    public string SesId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AppSessionBreakdown> Breakdown { get; set; }
}

public class AppSessionBreakdown
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AppSession")]
    public int ASId { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public virtual AppSession AppSession { get; set; }
}
```

My C# code for inserting is:

```
var breakdown = new AppSessionBreakdown {   ASId = snapSession.Id, FileName = fileName }; 
repositoryAppSessionsBreakdown.Insert(breakdown);
repositoryAppSessionsBreakdown.Save();
```

For some reasons, when I check the generated SQL, EF6 is adding an extra column which is not specified anywhere (`ApplicationUser_Id`) which insert statement is like this:

```
INSERT INTO `AppSessionBreakdowns`(`ASId`, FileName`, `ApplicationUser_Id`) VALUES (1, @gp1, NULL);
```

If I add an `ApplicationUser` column to the `AppSessionBreakdown` model, it does work but what can I do to prevent this as I don't want to add a useless column to make this just work.

ApplicationUser model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Surname")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public bool Activated { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "({0:dd MMM yyyy})")]
    [Display(Name = "Activated On")]
    public DateTime? ActivatedOn { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "({0:dd MMM yyyy})")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Logged In")]
    public DateTime? LastLoggedIn { get; set; }

    public int ContractorId { get; set; }

    public bool TestAccount { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TapInSite> TapInSite { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TapInLog> TapInLog { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AppSession> SnapAppSessions { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AppSessionBreakdown> SnapAppSessionsBreakdown { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {            
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code for the `ApplicationUser`-table, too?

Comment: Added  ApplicationUser thanks.

Comment: You are inheriting that column from IdentityUser,

Comment: Sorry, to bother you again, but could you please strip all the unneccessary code from you classes? I'd guess you'll need merely more than the IDs and references in your classes for a [mcve] :) And the redundant code just clutters the question.

Comment: You seem to be associating `AppSessionBreakdown` with your `ApplicationUser`, this is why probably EF expects `AppSessionBreakdown` to have a user id field as well.

Comment: @Shadow - Thank you! I added this ages ago and didn't even look at this class twice! This was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a relation between `ApplicationUser` and `AppSessionBreakdown` that is in a type of one-to-many, for example:

[image]

And result of that will be:

[image]

For more information read [Entity Framework Relationships and Navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Was including the column in the ApplicationUser class which caused this as mentioned in comments.